# Fredholm Alternative for Singular ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, self-adjoint-operators

Consider the following inhomogeneous boundary value problem,

$$t^2 u'' + tpu' +qu = f(t), \ t \in [-1,1], \ \ u(1) = \alpha, \ u(-1) = \beta,$$

where $p$ and $q$ are constants.

I would like to determine a condition for the existence of a solution to this problem using the Fredholm alternative. To use it, I need to express the ODE above in self-adjoint form, $$-(a(t)u'(t))' + b(t)u = \tilde{f}.$$ However, doing so involves steps which are irreversible, i.e multiplying both sides of the differential equation by a power of $t$, which may take the value $t = 0$. This means that the self-adjoint equation is not equivalent to the original. Does this render the Fredholm alternative unusable?

How could I determine a condition for the existence of a solution to this BVP?

Comment: the equation is cauchy euler.

Comment: Yes, how does this help to determine whether a solution exists?

Comment: The fredholm alternative is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \phi_{h}(x) dx = 0 $  where $\phi_{h}(x)$ is the homogeneous solution. If it doesn't equal zero then it has no solutions. For $\lambda =0 $  and that is zero then there are infinite solutions.

Comment: There may be two solutions to the  homogeneous problem, but boundary values or the interval that we are considering may force the coefficient of one or both to be zero. Suppose we have two solutions, $\phi_1, \phi_2$, resulting in general homogeneous solution $\phi_h = c_1 \phi_1 + c_2 \phi_2$, but boundary conditions force $c_2 = 0$. Then suppose $\int_a^b f(x) \phi_1(x)dx = 0$. Does this ensure the existence of a solution?

Comment: Or do we still need to consider $\int_a^b f(x) \phi_2(x)dx$ and have it equal to zero to ensure existence?

Comment: if $\phi_{h} \neq 0 $ and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \phi_{h} (x) dx =0$  then we'd have existence.  $\phi_{h}(x)$ could be multiple eigenfunctions $  the way to look at is the forcing term is orthogonal to all the homogeneous solutions i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RHowe remarked, 
the homogeneous equation $t^2 u'' + t p u' + q u = 0$ is Cauchy-Euler.   Its indicial roots are $r_\pm = (1-p \pm \sqrt{(1-p)^2 - 4 q})/2$.  Thus if those are distinct, the general solution of the homogeneous equation for $t > 0$ is $c_+ t^{r_+} + c_- t^{r_-}$.  Now since you want a solution on an interval containing $0$, a lot depends on whether $r_+$ and $r_-$ have positive, negative or $0$ real parts.  A solution $t^a$ with $\text{Re}(a) > 0$ can be continuously continued to $t < 0$ as $c |t|^a$ (the fact that this may not be differentiable at $t=0$ is not significant because the coefficients of $u'$ and $u''$ are $0$ there).  Moreover, there's an extra degree of freedom because the coefficient $c$ is arbitrary.  On the other hand, a solution with $\text{Re}(a) \le 0$ can't be made continuous at $t=0$ (except in the case $a=0$, where we take $t^0=1$ for all $t$)).

For example, consider the case $p=q=1$, where the indicial roots are $\pm i$.  The general solution of the homogeneous equation for $t > 0$ is $c_1 \cos(\ln(t)) + c_2 \sin(\ln(t))$, which has no limit as $t \to 0+$ unless $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, so there are no nontrivial solutions of the homogeneous equation.  If the non-homogeneous equation has a solution (and it does for every polynomial, as $u = t^n/(n^2+1)$ solves $t^2 u'' + t u' + u = t^n$), that solution is unique; it may or may not satisfy the boundary conditions.